# In a stream of event with state and time, how do i get a stream of state_duration?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

For instance, if I have a streams of BUTTON events, which can be created as

```
CREATE STREAM events (id STRING KEY, state STRING, time TIMESTAMP) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC=‘events’ value_format=‘avro’, partitions=3)
```

and populated with

```
INSERT INTO events (id, state, time) VALUES (‘BUTTON-1’, ‘OFF’, ‘2023-06-19T20:00:00Z’)
INSERT INTO events (id, state, time) VALUES (‘BUTTON-1’, ‘OFF’, ‘2023-06-19T20:01:00Z’)
INSERT INTO events (id, state, time) VALUES (‘BUTTON-1’, ‘ON’, ‘2023-06-19T20:02:00Z’)
INSERT INTO events (id, state, time) VALUES (‘BUTTON-1’, ‘ON’, ‘2023-06-19T20:03:00Z’)
INSERT INTO events (id, state, time) VALUES (‘BUTTON-1’, ‘OFF’, ‘2023-06-19T20:04:00Z’)
INSERT INTO events (id, state, time) VALUES (‘BUTTON-1’, ‘ON’, ‘2023-06-19T20:05:00Z’)
INSERT INTO events (id, state, time) VALUES (‘BUTTON-1’, ‘OFF’, ‘2023-06-19T20:06:00Z’)
```

I want to get a stream of duration, something similar to

```
ID       | ON_TIME                | DURATION
BUTTON-1 | ‘2023-06-19T20:02:00Z’ | 120000
BUTTON-1 | ‘2023-05-19T20:02:00Z’ |  60000
```

Different button id should be processed separately, AND the duration is calculated from the first `ON` state to the next `OFF` state.

**My Attempt**

1. create 2 streams with ‘ON’ state and ‘OFF’ state respectively

```
    CREATE STREAM on_events AS SELECT * FROM events WHERE state = ‘ON’;
    CREATE STREAM off_events AS SELECT * FROM events WHERE state = ‘OFF’;
```

2. Join the stream, and resort to table since I cant aggregate to produce stream

```
    CREATE TABLE on_next_off AS
        SELECT on_events.id AS id, on_events.time AS on_time, min(off_events.time) as off_time
        FROM on_events
        INNER JOIN OFF_JOINS ON on_events.id = off_events.id
        WHERE on_events.time < off_events.time
        GROUP BY on_events.id, on_events.time
```

3. Note that we only need to get the first on to next off. I have to resort to ARRAY_MIN(COLLECT_LIST(…)) dues to ksqldb min aggregation restriction on table. The timestamps are converted to UNIX before subtraction, omitted below for brevity.

```
    CREATE TABLE on_duration AS
        SELECT id, on_time, off_time - ARRAY_MIN(COLLECT_LIST(on_time)) as duration
        FROM on_next_off
        GROUP BY id, on_time
```

This seems to be very inefficient to me, even if it does what I want.

Can this be done in a more efficient way, preferably without using UDF? Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: This video includes a duration calculation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpLNK34tp2o

Comment: @OneCricketeer This might not be applicable for me.
1. For the calculation of lap time, they have a table that store the last time when a lap event happens. Doing something similar here will results in calculcation of duration from last ON to next OFF instead of first ON to next OFF
2. For calculation of max brake duration, they explicitly said that the sensor won’t output anything in between the time when the break is fully pressed and released. This is different from my scenario, where I can have an ON following an ON.